# Cluster pushpins Bing Maps AJAX Control v7 WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I have a Bing Maps AJAX Control for WP7, v7 (Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Map), with several pushpins that I want to cluster.

The only references I've found so far mention the VEShapeLayer.SetClusterConfiguration method, such as [the one mentioned in the official Microsoft Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc161072.aspx). However, looking at [Hanne's Virtual Earth](http://jkebeck.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/bing-maps-ajax-control-version-7-adding-vector-data/) it appears these classes have been replaced since version 6.3, thus rendering the SetClusterConfiguration method useless.

How can I cluster pushpins in the v7 of the Bing Maps AJAX Control? The only reference I've found so far is [the Bing Maps blog](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2011/03/01/bing-maps-v7-modular-design-and-client-side-clustering.aspx), but any other pointers (or perhaps a library that already implements it) would be GREATLY welcome :D

Thanks for your time! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Interactive SDK has a demonstration of client side clustering

http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#LoadingDynamicModule1

note: run register module -> load module -> enable clustering

Also, did you download the code [here](https://skydrive.live.com/embedicon.aspx/BingMapsv7/BMv7.ClientSideClustering.zip?cid=0d35222484a76a01&sc=documents)?

Notice it is V7. I got the code from this [blog post](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2011/03/01/bing-maps-v7-modular-design-and-client-side-clustering.aspx).

Don't worry about writing your own cluster algorithm yet. The default cluster algorithm in the given code is good enough for the start.

Comment: Don't worry, I already did my own algorithm using the method used in your last blog post. Thanks for the help anyways! :D

Comment: The default client side clustering is slow and buggy.  We had to implement our own server side clustering in sql to have something useful.

Comment: How can I add push points to a layer, for example the red layer?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to manually calculate the clustering. How to do so depends purely on your data source.

And I haven't seen any generic libraries for it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have a lightweight library at https://github.com/rtsinani/PinClusterer, inspired by Google Maps clusterer. You can see a demo here http://lugolabs.com/projects/pinclusterer.